# Wordpress website navigation bar disappears after I upload my website to a live server

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

After completing my WordPress development using Xampp the navigation bar was working fine. After I uploaded it in the live server, the navigation bar disappeared. Kindly help

Comment: please check in console and  check error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the error can be caused by following

1. be sure that you rewrite all URL's of your local environment into live server one
2. check the version of PHP used on the server